# Getting attributes from android using appium

Tags: android, python, appium

How to get list of available attributes on android using appium?
I tried this construction

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
dir(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ideally to get the value of an attribute of en element on your application usign appium you can use the following :

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_ios_uiautomation('.elements()[0]')
String elName = el.get_attribute('name'))
```

where `name` could be replaced by the attribute you want to attain the value of.